# counting suit points for bridge game

Tags: java

So my **Hand** class contains this instance, and I am currently not getting any points to be distributed, and since I have a getter inside my **Card** class cards called `char getSuit()` I assume my code would work if I check for each suit and then counted how many cards dealt were from the suit and then distributed points accordingly.

Some more info on what `int countDistributionPoints()` should be doing...

Takes no parameters and returns an integer. It needs to count the number of Cards in each suit:

1. A suit with 3 cards or more counts for zero points.
2. A suit with 2 cards counts one point (this is called a doubleton)
3. A suit with 1 card counts 2 points (this is called a singleton)
4. A suit with 0 cards counts 3 points (this is called a void)

This method will add the points together and return that number.

```
/**
 * Counts the number of cards in each suit and will add points
 * for the suits value, so if 3 or more suits zero points,
 * 2 suits 1 point, 1 suit 2 points, 0 suits 3 points
 */
public int countDistributionPoints()
{
    int countPoints = 0;
    int count = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        char suit = cards[i].getSuit();

        if (cards[i].getSuit() == 'C')
            count++;
        else if (cards[i].getSuit() == 'D')
            count++;
        else if (cards[i].getSuit() == 'H')
            count++;
        else if (cards[i].getSuit() == 'S')
            count++;
        
        if (count >= 3)
            countPoints = 0;
        else if (count == 2)
            countPoints++;
        else if (count == 1)
            countPoints += 2;
        else if (count == 0)
            countPoints += 3;
    }

    return countPoints;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Bridge, so I'm just going on your description, but give this a go:

```
public int countDistributionPoints()
{
    int points = 0;
    int cCards = 0, dCards = 0, hCards = 0, sCards = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        char suit = cards[i].getSuit();

        if (suit == 'C')
            cCards++;
        else if (suit == 'D')
            dCards++;
        else if (suit == 'H')
            hCards++;
        else if (suit == 'S')
            sCards++;
    }

    points += calculateSuitScore(cCards);
    points += calculateSuitScore(dCards);
    points += calculateSuitScore(hCards);
    points += calculateSuitScore(sCards);

    return points;
}

int calculateSuitScore(int numCards) {
    int points = 0;

    if (numCards >= 3)
        points = 0;
    else if (numCards == 2)
        points++;
    else if (numCards == 1)
        points += 2;
    else if (numCards == 0)
        points += 3;

    return points;
}
```

Basically, I think your problem was that you needed a separate count for each of the suits.

Comment: Sweet this code works! However I need it to work all within 1 method class.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. You need it in a single method? Splitting it into two methods doesn't have any functional effect but is neater and more readable.